# Flickr & Vimeo integration in iOS7 using ACAccount

Tags: ios, ios7, flickr

In iOS7 Flickr & Vimeo are also integrated with the device in addition to FB and Twitter. I wanted to use `ACAccount` api's to do the the integration just like Facebook & Twitter in iOS6.

For Facebook integration we can use the api like:

```
 ACAccountType* accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
                              ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
```

Similarly I wanted to get it for Flickr, but there are no new identifiers added in `ACAccountType.h` file.

Now I am wondering how can I do the integration for Flickr? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the user perspective there is integration of flicker & Vimeo in iOS 7 same as Facebook and Twitter. But in perspective to iOS Developer there is no change of Flickr and Vimeo integration in `iOS 7`.

**Why ?** For Native implementation of Social networks (Facebook,twitter), there are two main frameworks 1.Accounts 2. Social framework. When i made a demo app and included both mentioned frameworks.Then i go to it's header files. `What exactly these files said ?`

In SocialServiceType.h From Social Framework :-

```
 SOCIAL_EXTERN NSString *const SLServiceTypeTwitter NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0);
 SOCIAL_EXTERN NSString *const SLServiceTypeFacebook NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0);
 SOCIAL_EXTERN NSString *const SLServiceTypeSinaWeibo NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0);
 SOCIAL_EXTERN NSString *const SLServiceTypeTencentWeibo NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0);
 SOCIAL_EXTERN NSString *const SLServiceTypeLinkedIn NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, NA);
```

Above code defines there is no Flickr and Vimeo with their highest version support in `iOS 7`.

Hope this helps you !!!